# Igraph unknown index

Tags: r, igraph

> Simply_Graph <- simplify(graph)
>
> kc <- cluster_fast_greedy(as.undirected(Simply_Graph))
>
> length(kc)
>
> sizes(kc)
>
> membership(kc)
>
> plot(kc,graph,vertex.label =NA, vertex.size=3,edge.arrow.size=.3 )

I get this error:
**Error in simple_vs_index(x, ii, na_ok) : Unknown vertex selected**

Any soluton ?

Answer (score 0):

You should plot `Simply_Graph` not `graph`.

Comment: I tried changing to Simly_Graph as follows but it still returns the same error